# Using a MsgBox and If Then to open another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code that if an individual clicks "Yes" on the popup msgbox that they are directed to another worksheet and specific cell.

My question is if it's possible to have multiple msgboxes based on a selected cell?  If someone was to select E34 having it popup the correct corresponding msgbox?  While using an If Then to direct to the correct page/cell?

All the worksheets are within in one workbook document.

```
Sub PopupBox()

    Dim answer As Integer

    answer = MsgBox("Add Comments or Images to Category?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Comment")

    If answer = vbYes Then

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Comments").Range ("B7")

    Else
        'do nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim ans As VbMsgBoxResult`, not `Integer`. This will drop down the available results when typing out `If answer = ....`

Comment: Do you actually have a question. There are only statements in your post no questions. And in Excel when you don't know how to do something, record it (Alt + T, M, R) and look what excel did.

Comment: @urdearboy that is cleaner but it doesn't really matter, since `VbMsgNoxResult` is a single digit integer.

Comment: @urdearboy `VbMsgBoxResult` is an enumeration. It resolves to `Const vbyes = 6` so the same as `as Integer`. Enumerations are used by the VBA's editor for autosense.

Comment: @JohnColeman more of a suggestion, although re-reading it’s not clear it is one.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon This is from object browser `Const vbYes = 6`. So it is defined as a `long`. The enumeration is only used by the IDE editor for autosense not the VBA language. I don't care if someone defines that long as `vbMsgBoxResult` (which means as long) or `as long`. You said not to do correct code.

Comment: @Noodles I'm not sure what your point is. Every enum is a constant, yes. Are you saying we should be avoiding enum types because they're just numbers under the hood?

Comment: No I'm saying the code was fine as it is. There is nothing wrong with it at all. You just don't like that style of coding.

Comment: @Noodles correct, I've reviewed my fair share of VBA code through the years, and I like my code readable and explicit, without magic numbers, and with as little cognitive load as possible. `MsgBox` returns a `VbMsgBoxResult` enum, therefore capturing its result in a `VbMsgBoxResult` variable is preferable, despite `Integer` or `Long` being just as valid as `Double` or heck, `Byte` if you like. Seeing `Dim answer As Integer` and then `If answer = vbYes` uselessly prompts the question why `answer` wasn't declared `As VbMsgBoxResult`, is all: consistency makes code objectively better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put everyone's excellent comments into code (and add in a small change of my own):

```
Sub PopupBox()
    If MsgBox("Add Comments or Images to Category?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Comment") = vbYes Then
         ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Comments").Activate
         ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Comments").Range ("B7")
    End If
End Sub
```

In most cases I would have done exactly as you did in assigning the MsbBox response to a variable, but in something this simple, I wouldn't bother with the extra code and would simply put the MsgBox directly into the "If".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select that cell, you need to first activate the sheet:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Comments").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Comments").Range("B7").Select
```